# VK API Получение сообщений

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Как вывести список сообщений в вк. Общался с поддержкой дали доступ к сообщениям, пытаюсь вывести сообщение но ничего не происходит. Я выяснил, он не заходит в метод  public void onComplete(VKResponse response). Какие есть пути решения проблемы?

Код для получения сообщения:

```
Button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            VKRequest request = VKApi.messages().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.COUNT));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),request.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                @Override

                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

                    super.onComplete(response);

                    VKApiGetMessagesResponse getMessagesResponse = (VKApiGetMessagesResponse) response.parsedModel;
                    VKList<VKApiMessage> list = getMessagesResponse.items;

                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(VKApiMessage msg : list){
                        arrayList.add(msg.body);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,arrayList);
                    List_message.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Код всего приложения:

```
private String[] score = new String[]{VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.MESSAGES};
ListView List_message;
Button Button_update;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iniciailzation_components();

    VKSdk.login(this, score);

    Button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            VKRequest request = VKApi.messages().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.COUNT));
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),request.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                @Override

                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

                    super.onComplete(response);

                    VKApiGetMessagesResponse getMessagesResponse = (VKApiGetMessagesResponse) response.parsedModel;
                    VKList<VKApiMessage> list = getMessagesResponse.items;

                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(VKApiMessage msg : list){
                        arrayList.add(msg.body);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,arrayList);
                    List_message.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
            });
        }
    });




}

private void iniciailzation_components(){
    List_message = findViewById(R.id.List_message);
    Button_update = findViewById(R.id.Button_update);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
        @Override

        // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
        public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
            // Вывод списка друзей
           VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
            request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    super.onComplete(response);

                    VKList list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;

                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
                    List_message.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
            });

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Good",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Надо полагать, что заходит он в onError. В котором можно узнать, какая именно ошибка произошла. Возможно, вы токен не прикрепили к запросу.

Comment: Авторизация проходит успешно, я даже вывожу список друзей, по кнопке должны выводиться мои сообщения, но ничего не происходит, и даже еслиб он уходил в onError мне бы это отображалось @ЮрийСПб♦

Comment: ... но не выводятся. Если они есть, то у вас какая-то ошибка. Переопределить метод для ошибок класса VKRequestListener и выведите в логи и смотрите что там

Comment: Я так понимаю, что сейчас не работает метод VKApi.messages().get @ЮрийСПб♦

Comment: Да, это вполне возможно. Когда-то, вроде, всё у всех работало, а потом, вроде, отключили для всех и надо выпрашивать у тех. поддержки ВК разрешение личное на использование фичи. Если вы с ними по этому поводу общались уже - попробуйте уточнить в чём дело. Иначе - стоит им написать и запросить разрешение.

Comment: Кстати, можете поделиться опытом получения доступа от модераторов ВК?)) Ибо мне сказали, что никаких доступов не нужно, всё работает напрямую... Так сказать, вежливо послали))

Answer (score 0):

1.) Добавьте метод `onError()`. И в нём сможете увидеть свою ошибку.

```
@Override
public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
    super.onComplete(response);
}

@Override
public void onError(VKError error) {
    super.onError(error);
}
```

2.) У вас ошибка в том, что вы хотите получить список сообщений не тем методом, который нужен. Вам нужен `messages.getDialogs`. На настоящий момент: `messages.getConversations`.

3.) Так как пользуетесь старым API, то советую делать запросы таким образом:

```
new VKRequest("messages.getConversations", VKParameters.from(
        VKApiConst.COUNT, 20))
        .executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
               super.onComplete(response);
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(VKError error) {
               super.onError(error);
           }
});
```